# Is it possible to configure timeout for Delegted Authentication Webservice?

Tags: delegated-authentication

Is it possible to configure timeout for Delegted Authentication Webservice ?
This is another approach supported by salesforce  where an external webservice is invoked to validate username/password.  I could not able to find how to set timeout configuration for this webservice technically 10 secs is a huge amount of time for login but still I want to configure around 25 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't configure the timeout for Delegated Auth.